REAPER: Switching between ASIO and WASAPI devices
Sometimes I record and monitor music with an ASIO device like Focusrite or Behringer XR18 and sometimes it's just me and my laptop and I want to work using the sound card at hand, in this case Realtek in an HP Envy running Windows 11.  But when I switch from ASIO to WASAPI, the sound just vanishes and I get the "[audio device closed]" message, no matter what I try.
I've looked at the routing and I've adjusted the Windows 11 sound control source but all my projects will refuse to play. When I do get them to play, no sound emerges. But sometimes, sometimes it plays just fine. It's driving me crazy. Is there some protocol I should use when I switch between ASIO and WASAPI?
I'm so desperate, I've even tried to install a Realtek ASIO driver from the Microsoft Update Catalog at https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=realtek%20asio but that dead-ended too because
dism /online /add-package /packagepath:{CAB file name}
fails.

The solution that finally worked for me was to install the Steinberg ASIO driver and use that.
